# VFS resource required a bean named 'omapmDataSource' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Boot. The code is Sring Batch which converts data from Outsystems database to xmls.

I am upgrading the code from spring boot 1.4.0 to the latest 2.7.2.

Currently using JDK8 & Gradle 6.9

The code gets deployed to wildfly (RHEL7/Jboss7)

I have migrated the code but the logs show some issues while starting the service. It cannot find Bean "omapmDataSource" but it is clearly defined.

It says: **Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'omapmDataSource' available**

**The build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.2")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

version = '1.5'
war {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    archiveName 'ApplicationDataExtractor.war'
    metaInf { from 'src/main/resources/META-INF/*' }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.70'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.2'
    //implementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.5.2'
    
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.3.22'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.10'
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ojdbc7.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/ucp.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar')
    implementation files('jdbclibs/CouchbaseIntegration-1.04.jar')
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:4.4.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase:2.7.2'  
    implementation 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:3.3.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.2'
    
    
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.10'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.36'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {

    into "lib"

    from configurations.runtime

}
task allDeps {
doLast {
    println "All Dependencies:"
    allprojects.each { p ->
        println()
        println " $p.name ".center( 60, '*' )
        println()
        p.configurations.all.findAll { !it.allDependencies.empty }.each { c ->
            println " ${c.name} ".center( 60, '-' )
            c.allDependencies.each { dep ->
                println "$dep.group:$dep.name:$dep.version"
            }
            println "-" * 60
        }
    }
    }
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "com.*SomePackageName*.om.apm.batch.ApplicationDataExtractorBoot"
}

    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
}
```

**The Data Source Configuration File consisting the Bean(Pls ignore *SomePackageName*, I replaced it from actual name):**

```
package com.*SomePackageName*.om.apm.batch.config;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

@Configuration
@Component
@MapperScan("com.*SomePackageName*.om.apm.mapping")
@ComponentScan({"com.*SomePackageName*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.*SomePackageName*")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Bean(name = "omapmDataSource")
    @Profile("server")
    public DataSource omapmDataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        final String dataSourceName = this.environment.getProperty("omapm.datasource");
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(dataSourceName);
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "omapmDataSource")
    @Profile("mock")
    public DataSource omapmDataSourceMock() {

        final String user = this.environment.getProperty("omapm.jdbc.user");
        final String password = this.environment.getProperty("omapm.jdbc.password");
        final String url = this.environment.getProperty("omapm.jdbc.url");

        return this.oracleDataSource(url, user, password);
    }

    private DataSource oracleDataSource(String url, String user, String password) {

        OracleDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new OracleDataSource();

            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setUser(user);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR  : ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;

    }
    
    @Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
    @Primary
    //@Profile("mock")
    public DataSource batchDataSourceMock() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        //dataSource.setDriverClass());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/apps/hsqldb/hsqldb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(omapmDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.*SomePackageName*.om.apm.batch.domain");
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new Resource[] {
                new ClassPathResource("entity-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("application-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("iamapplication-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("riskletter-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("accesshistory-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("hotpeople-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("referencecode-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("lettertable-mapper.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("userRoles-mapper.xml")});
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDataExtractorBatchConfiguration file which imports stuff from DataSourceConfiguration, etc:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAsync
@Component
@Import({ DataSourceConfiguration.class, CouchbaseConfiguration.class, BusinessBureauDataCouchbaseConfiguration.class,
        ActivityLogCouchbaseConfiguration.class, CRACouchbaseConfiguration.class,
        GeneratedDocsCouchbaseConfiguration.class })
@PropertySource("file:/usr/share/jbossas/standalone/configuration/application.properties")
@PropertySource("file:/usr/share/jbossas/standalone/configuration/product.properties")
public class ApplicationDataExtractorBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationDataExtractorBatchConfiguration.class);

//  private static int CHUNK_SIZE = 30;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourceTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
            ResourcelessTransactionManager resourceTransactionManager) throws Exception {

        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(
                resourceTransactionManager);

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory)
            throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }
}
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-08 08:43:03,073 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

VFS resource ["/content/ApplicationDataExtractor.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/*SomePackageName*/om/apm/mapping/EntityMapper.class"] required a bean named 'omapmDataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'omapmDataSource' in your configuration.

2022-08-08 08:43:03,074 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ApplicationDataExtractor.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ApplicationDataExtractor.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchTriggerForCSVFile': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'riskLettersSummaryDataExtractorStep'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'riskLettersSummaryDataExtractorStep' defined in class path resource [com/*SomePackageName*/om/apm/batch/config/ApplicationDataExtractorBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'riskLettersSummaryDataExtractorStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'riskLettersDataReader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityMapper' defined in VFS resource ["/content/ApplicationDataExtractor.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/*SomePackageName*/om/apm/mapping/EntityMapper.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/*SomePackageName*/om/apm/batch/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'omapmDataSource' available
```

For full logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g7hX2vFZR1THhTpKBeW10IEh_xqtZ97Q/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The `omapmDataSource` dataSource bean is defined under the `server` profile. Accoding to the error, this bean is not defined, probably because you are starting your application with the default profile (in which that bean won't be visible).

Make sure you start your application with the `server` profile, or make that bean available to the default profile.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. How do I start my application with server profile or the other thing?